# In Revelation 16 who is the wrath of God being poured out on?

Tags: revelation

On who is the wrath of God being poured out on? Aren't the wicked harvested in revelation 14?

> Rev 16:1 - Then I heard a loud voice from the temple saying to the
> seven angels, “Go, pour out on the earth the seven bowls of God’s
> wrath.”

Comment: Are you making the assumption that the prophecies in Revelation are only sequential?  Could not some be parallel as evidenced by the two references you quote?

Comment: So they might be parallel? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Correctly saying that the wicked are harvested in chapter 14 does not mean that they cannot be 'the wicked' who God pours his wrath upon in chapter 16. This is because Revelation has seven sections, which are not chronological, but which are repetitive (going back to add to what was said in previous sections). A picture is being built up, with layers of further principles and meanings being detailed. This is the way the Revelation is structured:

The 1st opening - 1:9 to the end of ch. 3

The 2nd opening - 4:1 to the end of ch. 6

The 3rd opening - 7:1 to the end of ch. 11

The 4th opening - 12:1 to the end of ch. 14

The 5th opening - 15:1 to the end of ch. 16

The 6th opening - 17:1 to the end of ch. 19

The 7th opening - 20:1 to ch. 22 vs. 5.

Here is how the author (who details those sections and expounds the prophecy) illustrates a good way of viewing the whole:

> "Like seven parallel - but not equal - tracks traversing the side of a
> mountain, each appearing at one extremity and passing from sight at
> the other, one above another in parallel, yet varying in length
> proportionately as the mountain increases in height to the topmost
> peak, so appears the Book of Revelation.
>
> It follows that each ascending traverse affords a different view,
> yields a distinctive perspective, presents a new aspect, *yet of the
> same basic journey in principle from one extremity of departure to the
> other*. But as the elevation heightens, so the journey decreases, and
> the heavenly vision unfolds, with the more astonishing clarity, till
> at last all lies revealed before and beneath the spiritual gaze of the
> discerning reader.
>
> The lowest traverse gives the greater, earthly detail, whereas the
> highest, wellnigh in the clouds of heaven, presents a glimpse of that
> vast panoramic sweep of time and space from the vantage of the
> heavenly places. This suddenly makes everything clear, and in an
> instant sets all in perspective...
>
> Each distinct parallel opening in turn reveals new principles
> enlightening the faith of the saints and the *ecclesia*. As one
> opening gives way to another, so the vision becomes more and more
> focussed upon the great day of the Lord..." *The Revelation of Jesus
> Christ*, pp. 53 & 452 John Metcalfe

All this is necessary to show that ch. 14 gives some details of God's wrath being poured out on the wicked at the one harvest, which has two reapings. But 14:20 marks the end of the 4th section - it is marked with judgment of the wicked. Now think of having a sorbet, to clear your spiritual pallet before the next 'course', which starts at 15:1 until the end of ch. 16. The judging of the wicked is at the end of that new, 5th section, but with more details. Now we get specifics about Armageddon. The symbolic "cities of the nations" are destroyed, and all those people who refused to repent at the angelic outpouring of the seven ***last*** plagues, blaspheming God instead, know God's wrath. The 5th section ends at 16:21. Then comes a new section with 17:1, giving many details about Babylon the Great, further to that one verse mention of her in 16:19.

So, the answer to your question is that **it is the same group of wicked people in ch. 14 that also experience the same wrath of God in ch. 16**.

Answer (score 0):

I have published my own account of the sequence of events in Revelation, and this is a summary of the relevant portions;

There is a sense in which the "end" is reached when the seventh angel blows his trumpet. "The kingdom of the world HAS BECOME the kingdom of our Lord and of his Christ" (ch11 v15). So we have reached the "last hour" of the world, at least. What follows in the second half of the book is partly a symbolic description of the "last hour" and partly a succession of commentaries on what's happening. This has the effect of delaying the crisis.

The next two chapters are, in film-making terms, a "flashback" with the usual purpose of explaining the background to what's happening. Ch12 brings up the Atonement; Satan the accuser has been overcome "by the blood of the Lamb" (ch12 v11). Believers have been taken out of his power. In his resentment (v12) he determines to accuse them before men instead, and sets up the tribulation of the church (ch13) as a way of getting his revenge.

Ch14 is a commentary on all these things. It is a series of warnings that the persecutors and those who take their side will be judged.

Ch16 contains the sequence of the seven vials, which is essentially the sequence of the seven trumpets. The difference is that the trumpets are announcing the beginning of the process, and the vials are making things much worse and thus announcing the climax. The seventh vial brings us to "one minute to midnight", whereas the seventh trumpet brought us only to "eleven o'clock".

The real climax is to be Armageddon, which is God's judgment on the rulers of the world (as in Joel ch3 v14). But this battle is postponed. Nothing happens until ch19, which seems the return of Christ to the world in judgment (see 2 Thessalonians ch1 v7). The intervening chapters are occupied by another piece of "commentary", in the form of a belated description of the Babylon which is being destroyed.

Ch14 was a warning about the final event. Ch16 v1 opens a description of the immediate precursors of the final event.

Comment: The repeated description of the last judgment plainly indicates that the entire book is repetitive, covering the Church Age from Christ's ascension to His return (and, thence, immediate Judgment). The system you propose does not fit the evidence of the text of the book.

Comment: @Nigel J I've examined the text of the book fairly carefully, as a whole. I stand by my analysis.

Comment: I recommend John Metcalfe's thorough (600 page) explanation of the four interpretations of the Apocalypse (Contemporary, Historicist, Futurist and Resumptive) then his own opening up of the entire revelation by the Resumptive view of seven sections which view the same period of time from seven, increasingly spiritual, aspects. I do recommend you consider it. Regards. [John Metcalfe Publishing Trust](https://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/apostolic_foundation.htm).

Comment: @Nigel J I can only recommend the best complete interpretation I know; https://www.amazon.com/Silence-Heaven-Survey-Book-Revelation/dp/1597556734

Answer (score 0):

The destruction of the wicked as a result of God's wrath is described several times in the Book of revelation:

- Rev 6:15-17 - the wicked ask to be destroyed when the see the Lamb on the throne
- Rev 11:18 - the time to destroy those who destroy the earth
- Rev 14:19, 20 - wicked crushed in the great wine-press of the wrath of God
- Rev 16:18-21 - wicked destroyed by great hailstones
- Rev 18:8 - Babylon and its inhabitants consumed by fire
- Rev 19:15-21 - wicked destroyed in the wine-press of the wrath of God and the birds gorged themselves on their flesh
- Rev 20:9, 10 - fire comes down from heaven and consumes the wicked
- Rev 20:15 - wicked thrown into the lake of fire

Thus, there are numerous scenes describing the destruction of the wicked which are presumably, at least in this detail, parallel.

Answer (score -1):

We need to focus on some definitions so that we don’t read into the text any current meanings of our day and time in order to know what Rev. 16 is about.

The word translated as “earth” in Rev. 16:1 is Strong’s Gr. 1093, “ge”.  It means  the land, region, soil, country, or inhabitants of a region. (Source: [Biblehub](https://We%20need%20to%20focus%20on%20some%20definitions%20so%20that%20we%20don%E2%80%99t%20read%20into%20the%20text%20any%20current%20meanings%20of%20our%20day%20and%20time%20in%20order%20to%20know%20what%20Rev.%2016%20is%20about.%20%20The%20word%20translated%20as%20%E2%80%9Cearth%E2%80%9D%20in%20Rev.%2016:1%20is%20Strong%E2%80%99s%20Gr.%201093,%20%E2%80%9Cge%E2%80%9D.%20%20It%20means%20%20the%20land,%20region,%20soil,%20country,%20or%20inhabitants%20of%20a%20region.%20(Source:%20https://biblehub.com/greek/1093.htm)%20%20It%20was%20used%20in%20prophesy%20for%20the%20people%20of%20a%20land%20or%20country%20under%20judgment,%20to%20whom%20the%20prophet%20was%20sent%20to%20warn.%20%20In%20speaking%20to%20the%20Israelite%20in%20the%20desert%20wilderness,%20Moses%20said,%20%20%20%3E%E2%80%9DGive%20ear,%20O%20ye%20heavens,%20and%20I%20will%20speak;%20and%20hear,%20O%20earth,%20the%20words%20of%20my%20mouth.%E2%80%9D%20%20(Deu.%2032:1,%20KJV)%20%20Speaking%20to%20the%20people%20of%20Judah%20and%20Jerusalem,%20Isaiah%20said,%20%20%20%3E%E2%80%9DHear,%20O%20heavens,%20and%20give%20ear,%20O%20earth:%20for%20the%C2%A0Lord%C2%A0hath%20spoken,%20I%20have%20nourished%20and%20brought%20up%20children,%20and%20they%20have%20rebelled%20against%20me.%E2%80%9D%20%20(Isa.%201:2,%20KJV)%20%20Context%20determines%20the%20usage,%20so%20it%20is%20critical%20to%20know%20to%20whom%20the%20prophet%20was%20speaking%20to%20know%20the%20land%20and%20people%20under%20judgment.%20%20It%20did%20not%20always%20mean%20the%20entire%20earth.%20%20Most%20often%20%E2%80%9Cearth%E2%80%9D%20was%20used%20in%20speaking%20to%20the%20people%20of%20Israel.%20But%20at%20other%20times%20God%20was%20directing%20the%20prophet%20to%20other%20nations.%20%20The%20prophesy%20against%20the%20king%20and%20nation%20of%20Babylon,%20%20%20%3E%E2%80%9DTherefore%20I%20will%20shake%20the%20heavens,%20and%20the%20earth%20shall%20remove%20out%20of%20her%20place,%20in%20the%20wrath%20of%20the%C2%A0Lord%C2%A0of%20hosts,%20and%20in%20the%20day%20of%20his%20fierce%20anger.%E2%80%9D%20%20(Isa.%2013:13,%20KJV)%20%20%20The%20earth%20that%20was%20to%20be%20removed%20out%20of%20its%20place%20was%20the%20nation%20of%20Babylon.%20%20%20%20Just%20as%20the%20word%20%E2%80%9Cearth%E2%80%9D%20depends%20upon%20the%20context%20of%20the%20scriptures,%20so%20does%20the%20word%20%E2%80%9Cheaven.%E2%80%9D%20%20When%20used%20in%20prophesy%20the%20word%20%E2%80%9Cheaven%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20ruling%20authorities%20of%20that%20land,%20or%20country.%20%20When%20Moses%20said%20%E2%80%9CHear,%20O%20heavens%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D%20he%20wasn%E2%80%99t%20calling%20God%20to%20hear%20him.%20%20Moses%20was%20speaking%20to%20one%20group%20of%20the%20people%20that%20were%20set%20as%20governors,%20or%20rulers%20of%20the%20Israelite%20which%20at%20that%20time%20were%20the%20Levitical%20priests.%20%20When%20Isaiah%20was%20speaking%20the%20prophesy%20to%20Babylon,%20the%20%E2%80%9Cheavens%E2%80%9D%20of%20that%20nation%20was%20the%20king,%20and%20all%20of%20his%20princes%20and%20governors%20that%20ruled%20over%20that%20dominion.%20%20The%20heavens%20of%20principalities%20and%20nations%20were%20the%20king%E2%80%99s%20smaller%20heavens%20over%20their%20nation,%20just%20as%20God%E2%80%99s%20heaven%20is%20over%20the%20whole%20earth.%20%20The%20word%20used%20for%20%E2%80%9Cworld%E2%80%9D%20in%20Rev.%2016:14%20is%20Strong%E2%80%99s%20Greek%203625:%20%E2%80%9Coikoumen%C3%A9:%20the%20inhabited%20earth%E2%80%9D%20and%20the%20definition%20is%20-%20%20%20%E2%80%9C(properly:%20the%20land%20that%20is%20being%20inhabited,%20the%20land%20in%20a%20state%20of%20habitation),%20the%20inhabited%20world,%20that%20is,%C2%A0the%20Roman%20world,%20for%20all%20outside%20it%20was%20regarded%20as%20of%20no%20account.%E2%80%9D%C2%A0%20(Source:%20https://biblehub.com/greek/3625.htm)%20%20It%20has%20the%20same%20meaning%20as%20in%20Luke%202:1%20where%20Caesar%20August%20called%20for%20a%20census%20over%20the%20entire%20%E2%80%9Cworld%E2%80%9D%20which%20could%20only%20be%20done%20for%20his%20kingdom%20and%20dominion%20of%20the%20Roman%20empire.%20The%20phrases%20%E2%80%9Cthe%20end%20of%20the%20earth%E2%80%9D%20(Deu.%2028:49)%20or%20%E2%80%9Cthe%20end%20of%20heaven%E2%80%9D%20(Isa.%2013:5)%20has%20the%20meaning%20of%20the%20borders%20of%20the%20land%20or%20nation%20to%20whom%20the%20prophet%20is%20speaking.%20%20So%20we%20first%20discover%20which%20prophet%20is%20speaking%20and%20which%20land%20or%20country%20he%20is%20warning%20to%20be%20able%20to%20know%20which%20%E2%80%9Cearth%E2%80%9D%20and%20people%20are%20the%20subject%20of%20the%20specific%20prophesy.%20The%20prophet%20of%20Revelation%20is%20Jesus%20Christ%20(Rev.%201:1).%20%20And,%20the%20people%20of%20this%20judgment%20were%20those%20of%20Jerusalem.%20%20%3E%E2%80%9DFor%20they%20have%20shed%20the%20blood%20of%20saints%20and%20prophets,%20and%20thou%20hast%20given%20them%20blood%20to%20drink;%20for%20they%20are%20worthy.%E2%80%9D%20%20(Rev.%2016:6,%20KJV)%20%20%3E%E2%80%9DO%20Jerusalem,%20Jerusalem,%20thou%20that%20killest%20the%20prophets,%20and%20stonest%20them%20which%20are%20sent%20unto%20thee,%C2%A0%E2%80%A6%E2%80%9D%20%20(Matt.%2023:37,%20KJV)%20%20The%20judgment%20of%20Rev.%2016%20is%20upon%20the%20same%20people%20and%20land%20as%20is%20the%20entirety%20of%20the%20book%20%E2%80%93%20Jerusalem,%20and%20all%20Judea,%20and%20surrounding%20areas%20of%20the%20Roman%20empire.%20%20The%20judgments%20of%20chap.%2016%20are%20the%20plagues%20God%20promised%20to%20bring%20upon%20them%20if%20they%20disobeyed%20and%20broke%20His%20covenant.%20%20%3E%E2%80%9D%C2%A0These%20are%20the%20words%20of%20the%20covenant,%20which%20the%C2%A0Lord%C2%A0commanded%20Moses%20to%20make%20with%20the%20children%20of%20Israel%C2%A0%E2%80%A6%20%20Lest%20there%20should%20be%20among%20you%20man,%20or%20woman,%20or%20family,%20or%20tribe,%20whose%20heart%20turneth%20away%20this%20day%20from%20the%C2%A0Lord%C2%A0our%20God,%E2%80%A6.%20So%20that%20the%20generation%20to%20come%20of%20your%20children%20that%20shall%20rise%20up%20after%20you,%20and%20the%20stranger%20that%20shall%20come%20from%20a%20far%20land,%20shall%20say,%20when%20they%20see%20the%20plagues%20of%20that%20land,%20and%20the%20sicknesses%20which%20the%C2%A0Lord%C2%A0hath%20laid%20upon%20it;%20%E2%80%9C%20(Deu.%2029:1,%2013,%2022,%20KJV)%20%20%3E%E2%80%9D%C2%A0And%20if%20ye%20walk%20contrary%20unto%20me,%20and%20will%20not%20hearken%20unto%20me;%20I%20will%20bring%20seven%20times%20more%20plagues%20upon%20you%20according%20to%20your%20sins.%E2%80%9D%20%20(Lev.%2026:21,%20KJV)%20%20%3E%E2%80%9D...Hear%20ye%20the%20word%20of%20the%C2%A0Lord,%20O%20kings%20of%20Judah,%20and%20inhabitants%20of%20Jerusalem;%20Thus%20saith%20the%C2%A0Lord%C2%A0of%20hosts,%20the%20God%20of%20Israel;%20Behold,%20I%20will%20bring%20evil%20upon%20this%20place,%C2%A0...Because%20they%20have%20forsaken%20me,%20and%20have%20estranged%20this%20place,%20and%20have%20burned%20incense%20in%20it%20unto%20other%20gods%E2%80%A6.And%20I%20will%20make%20this%20city%20desolate,%20and%20an%20hissing;%20every%20one%20that%20passeth%20thereby%20shall%20be%20astonished%20and%20hiss%20because%20of%20all%20the%20plagues%20thereof.%E2%80%9D%20%20(Jer.%2019:3,%204,%208,%20KJV)%20%20The%20prophesies%20of%20Revelation%20are%20not%20chronological,%20but%20thematic%20as%20a%20war%20correspondent%20will%20cover%20the%20war%20from%20different%20battle%20fronts.%20All%20of%20the%20prophesy%20of%20Revelation%20is%20revealed%20from%20the%20Old%20Testament%20prophesies%20upon%20Jerusalem.%20%20All%20of%20the%20judgment%20language%20is%20the%20same%20judgment%20language%20God%20used%20in%20the%20Old%20Testament%20scriptures%20and%20it%20was%20directed%20by%20His%20prophet%20Jesus%20Christ%20upon%20the%20wicked%20people%20of%20Jerusalem%20and%20Judea%20of%20the%201st%20century%20AD%20who%20had%20killed%20His%20saints%20and%20prophets%20and%20caused%20Him%20to%20be%20crucified%20upon%20that%20Roman%20cross.%20%20%20Further%20reading%20/%20study:%20Ezekiel%20in%20Revelation%20%E2%80%93%20Part%20I:%20Overview%20https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/07/13/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-i-overview-comparison/%20%20Ezekiel%20in%20Revelation%20%E2%80%93%20Part%20II:%20Sodom%20&%20Gomorrah%20https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/08/06/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-ii-sodom-gomorrah/%20%20Ezekiel%20in%20Revelation%20%E2%80%93%20Part%20III:%20Jerusalem,%20the%20Vine%20Tree%20and%20the%20Winepress%20https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/09/22/ezekiel-in-revelatio-part-iii-jerusalem-the-vine-tree-and-the-winepress/))  It was used in prophesy for the people of a land or country under judgment, to whom the prophet was sent to warn.

In speaking to the Israelite in the desert wilderness, Moses said,

> *”Give ear, O ye heavens, and I will speak; and hear, O earth, the words of my mouth.”*  (Deu. 32:1, KJV)

Speaking to the people of Judah and Jerusalem, Isaiah said,

> *”Hear, O heavens, and give ear, O earth: for the Lord hath spoken, I have nourished and brought up children, and they have rebelled against me.”*  (Isa. 1:2, KJV)

Context determines the usage, so it is critical to know to whom the prophet was speaking to know the land and people under judgment.  It did not always mean the entire earth.  Most often “earth” was used in speaking to the people of Israel. But, at other times God was directing the prophet to other nations.

The prophesy against the king and nation of Babylon,

> *”Therefore I will shake the heavens, and the earth shall remove out of her place, in the wrath of the Lord of hosts, and in the day of his fierce anger.”*  (Isa. 13:13, KJV)

In the prophesy of Isa. 13, the earth that was to be removed out of its place was the nation of Babylon.

Just as the word “earth” depends upon the context of the scriptures, so does the word “heaven.”  When used in prophesy the word “heaven” refers to the ruling authorities of that land, or country.  When Moses said *“Hear, O heavens…”* he wasn’t calling God to hear him.  Moses was speaking to one group of the people that were set as governors, or rulers of the Israelite which at that time were the Levitical priests.

When Isaiah was speaking the prophesy to Babylon, the “heavens” of that nation was the king, and all of his princes and governors that ruled over that kings' dominion.  The heavens of principalities and nations were the king’s smaller heavens over their nation, just as God’s heaven is over the whole earth.

The word used for “world” in Rev. 16:14 is Strong’s Greek 3625: “oikoumené: the inhabited earth” and the definition is -

“(properly: the land that is being inhabited, the land in a state of habitation), the inhabited world, that is, the Roman world, **for all outside it was regarded as of no account**.”  (Source: [Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/greek/3625.htm))

It has the same meaning as in Luke 2:1 where Caesar Augustus called for a census over the entire “world” which could only be done for his kingdom and dominion of the Roman empire.

The phrases “the end of the earth” (Deu. 28:49) or “the end of heaven” (Isa. 13:5) has the meaning of the borders of the land or nation to whom the prophet is speaking.

So, we first discover which prophet is speaking and which land or country he is warning to be able to know which “earth” and people are the subject of the specific prophesy. The prophet of Revelation is Jesus Christ (Rev. 1:1).  And, the people of this judgment were those of Jerusalem.

> *”For they have shed the blood of saints and prophets, and thou hast given them blood to drink; for they are worthy.”*  (Rev. 16:6, KJV)

> *”O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, thou that killest the prophets, and stonest them which are sent unto thee, …”*  (Matt. 23:37, KJV)

The judgment of Rev. 16 is upon the same people and land as is the entirety of the book – Jerusalem, and all Judea, and surrounding areas of the Roman empire.  The judgments of chap. 16 are the plagues God promised to bring upon them if they disobeyed and broke His covenant.

> *”These are the words of the covenant, which the Lord commanded Moses to make with the children of Israel …  Lest there should be among you man, or woman, or family, or tribe, whose heart turneth away this day from the Lord our God,…. So that the generation to come of your children that shall rise up after you, and the stranger that shall come from a far land, shall say, when they see the plagues of that land, and the sicknesses which the Lord hath laid upon it; “* (Deu. 29:1, 13, 22, KJV)

> *”And if ye walk contrary unto me, and will not hearken unto me; I will bring seven times more plagues upon you according to your sins.”*  (Lev. 26:21, KJV)

> *”...Hear ye the word of the Lord, O kings of Judah, and inhabitants of Jerusalem; Thus saith the Lord of hosts, the God of Israel; Behold, I will bring evil upon this place, ...Because they have forsaken me, and have estranged this place, and have burned incense in it unto other gods….And I will make this city desolate, and an hissing; every one that passeth thereby shall be astonished and hiss because of all the plagues thereof.”*  (Jer. 19:3, 4, 8, KJV)

The prophesies of Revelation are not chronological, but thematic as a war correspondent will cover the war from different battle fronts. All of the prophesy of Revelation is revealed from the Old Testament prophesies upon Jerusalem.  All of the judgment language is the same judgment language God used in the Old Testament scriptures and it was directed by His prophet Jesus Christ upon the wicked people of Jerusalem and Judea of the 1st century AD who had killed His saints and prophets and caused Him to be crucified upon that Roman cross.

Further reading / study:

Ezekiel in Revelation – Part I: Overview [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/07/13/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-i-overview-comparison/)

Ezekiel in Revelation – Part II: Sodom & Gomorrah [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/08/06/ezekiel-in-revelation-part-ii-sodom-gomorrah/)

Ezekiel in Revelation – Part III: Jerusalem, the Vine Tree and the Winepress [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2019/09/22/ezekiel-in-revelatio-part-iii-jerusalem-the-vine-tree-and-the-winepress/)

It's Not The End of the World - Part III: Judgement Language in the Old Testament [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/23/its-not-the-end-of-the-world-part-iii-judgment-language-in-the-old-testament/)

It's Not the End of the World - Part IV: Judgment Language in Both Old and New Testaments [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/23/its-not-the-end-of-the-world-part-iv-judgment-language-in-both-old-new-testaments/)